# Wordpress 5.1 upgrade has lost the parent theme JavaScript

Tags: themes, javascript, block-editor, footer, scripts

I have just upgraded from Wordpress 4.9 to 5.1, which obviously comes with Gutenberg.

One major problem I have is that the parent theme (BeTheme) JavaScript is not being loaded and instead the child theme JavaScript is being loaded for a second time.

After the point where `wp_footer()` is called I have this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://crmpicco.localhost/wp-content/themes/betheme/assets/animations/animations.min.js?ver=21.1.1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://crmpicco.localhost/wp-content/themes/betheme/assets/jplayer/jplayer.min.js?ver=21.1.1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://crmpicco.localhost/wp-content/themes/betheme/js/parallax/translate3d.js?ver=21.1.1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://crmpicco.localhost/wp-content/themes/crmpiccodotcom/js/scripts.js?ver=21.1.1.1'></script>
```

Whereas on my old installation the last line would be pointing to the parent theme JavaScript.

What has caused this to change in 5.1?

Comment: WordPress does not modify third-party themes. More than that, it does not care where your scripts are enqueued from.

Comment: Nothing has changed in WordPress that would cause this. Either the parent theme updated and changed something or you've made a change and forgotten about it. Can you share the code you're using to enqueue scripts? Or even how the parent theme enqueues them.

Answer (score 1):

I traced this back to the name of the `scripts.js` JavaScript file.

My parent theme (BeTheme) enqueues the main `scripts.js` like this:

`wp_enqueue_script('mfn-scripts', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts.js'), array('jquery'), MFN_THEME_VERSION, true);`

In my child theme `crmpiccodotcom/footer.php` I enqueue the scripts.js like this:

```
// include the crmpiccodotcom child theme JavaScript
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'crmpiccodotcom_enqueue_scripts');
function crmpiccodotcom_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        CHILD_THEME_URI. '/js/scripts.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
```

Seemingly the name caused a clash and the BeTheme used the child theme's `scripts.js` instead of it's own, so **the fix was to rename the child theme** `scripts.js` -> `crmpicco-scripts.js`

I believe the issue lies with the BeTheme, which I will take up with them, but certainly a file rename resolves this.